# Can't get timer event handler working

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

On page, I have UpdatePanel with Timer that works fine:

```
<asp:Content ID="content" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentholder" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"  ID="ScriptManager"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer" runat="server" Interval="10000" ></asp:Timer>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="MainUpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
<!-- some content, including repeaters... -->
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

I can't get event handler in code behind working though.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    }
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
_someFlag = true;
}
```

I can see during debug that `Timer.Tick +=` happens just fine, yet `_someFlag` never changes its value and `_someFlag = true;` never happens despite page itself updating correctly. What am I missing?

Comment: Might be that you haven't added a `new EventHandler` to the function `Timer_Tick`

Comment: is the `Timer` started anywhere ?

Comment: may this link will help full for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073703/call-tick-event-when-timer-starts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `OnTick="Timer_Tick"` attribute to your timer:

```
<asp:Timer runat="server" id="Timer1" Interval="10000" OnTick="Timer_Tick"></asp:Timer>
```

And remove below code from Page_Load:

```
Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put 'Timer' inside 'Update panel' & 'Content Template' tag to handle trigger event

Comment: Nope, still same result.